# Make a unique index or constraint to check overlapping DateTime columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm using `EF 6.2.0`, `EF Code-First`, `.NET 4.7`, `Azure SQL Database`.

I have an EF Code-First model, on which I need to enforce a constraint, so that a new row is **not** allowed to overlap the range in other `ValidFromUtc` and `ValidToUtc` `DateTime` columns. I would prefer the constraint to be enforced in the database and maintained by EF.

On my EF Model I have the following properties and `DataAnnotations`:

```cs
[Required, Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

[Required, Index("UniqueIndexName", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
public Guid OwnerAccountId { get; set; }

[Required, Index("UniqueIndexName", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
public Guid PartnerAccountId { get; set; }

// I need a range constraint between ValidFromUtc and ValidToUtc to be enforced somehow.
[Required, Index("UniqueIndexName", IsUnique = true, Order = 3)]
public DateTime ValidFromUtc { get; set; }

[Required, Index("UniqueIndexName", IsUnique = true, Order = 4)]
public DateTime ValidToUtc { get; set; }

// Etc. etc.
```

What I need is a way to enforce that a row for the given `OwnerAccountId`, `PartnerAccountId` fails to be inserted or updated, if its values for `ValidFromUtc` or `ValidToUtc` overlap with any existing rows.

Is it possible to implement the above constraint using (in order of preference):

- DataAnnotations?
- Fluent API?
- Computed columns?
- Insert/Update Triggers?
- Stored Procedures?

If so, how can it be done? Which is the better approach and why?

*The only solution I can think of right now, is creating an Insert/Update trigger.*

Any pointers are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't this be part of your business logic? Why do you want to offload this to EF or Db?

Comment: enforcing business rules via database is fine, I wouldn't use EF, but then again I'm db bias. Trigger is the knee jerk reaction but to some degree of the previous comment, wouldn't you want to know the the invalid ranges prior to your user inputting the record? I would use a user stored procedure to return all records with the ids and date ranges, validate the record prior to passing the info to the database. I would also use a trigger to ensure integrity but that's just because I don't trust app devs to never change their code, as a shortcut i.e. trust, but verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think a Trigger is the only option:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UniqueDates](
    [OwnerAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentAccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValidFromUtc] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [ValidToUtc] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UniqueDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OwnerAccountId] ASC,
    [ParentAccountId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UniqueDates] ([OwnerAccountId], [ParentAccountId], [ValidFromUtc], [ValidToUtc]) VALUES (1, 1, CAST(N'2018-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-01-03T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UniqueDates] ([OwnerAccountId], [ParentAccountId], [ValidFromUtc], [ValidToUtc]) VALUES (1, 2, CAST(N'2018-01-04T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-01-05T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UniqueDates] ([OwnerAccountId], [ParentAccountId], [ValidFromUtc], [ValidToUtc]) VALUES (2, 1, CAST(N'2018-01-06T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-01-08T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
GO
create trigger [trg_i_Test] on [UniqueDates]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   if exists (SELECT null
  FROM [TEST].[dbo].[UniqueDates] [from]
  Inner join [TEST].[dbo].[UniqueDates] [to] on ([from].ValidFromUtc between [to].ValidFromUtc and [to].ValidtoUtc) 
      and ([from].OwnerAccountId<>[to].OwnerAccountID or [from].ParentAccountId<>[to].ParentAccountID)
      )
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('These dates break the rules.' ,16,1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END 
   ELSE    
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO [UniqueDates]
         SELECT *
         FROM inserted
   END    
END
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UniqueDates] ([OwnerAccountId], [ParentAccountId], [ValidFromUtc], [ValidToUtc]) VALUES (2, 4, CAST(N'2018-01-07T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-01-09T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset))
GO
```

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Thanks for the implementation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want *everything* to come from EF then you'll have to use [EF Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx).  (note: I'm not a fan of Migrations at all).  This allows EF full control over the db (creation and migration etc), which also means you need to do a lot of database specific stuff in C# code (required fields, field types etc).   Then in the seed routine you'd write some code like:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand("CREATE CONSTRAINT /* etc etc */");
```

(If that's a little two raw, you can create your own Attributes to put on your EF Models and then use reflection to dynamically create custom constraints).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, exactly what I had in mind. Executing the CREATE and DROP trigger using:

`DbMigration.Sql(string sql, bool suppressTransaction = false, object anonymousArguments = null);`